# Is it possible to format text input so Python recognises it as a list?

Tags: python, list, python-2.7, input, user-input

I've got a console application that prompts the user to enter various inputs.  Works fine.

Now I'd like to add some additional parameters to the function that is called to allow the user to filter the results.  In particular, I'd like the user to be able to enter a date range, to return all records created in that time period.

I could add two separate parameters to the function, such as lowerDateLimit and upperDateLimit.  But it seems neater to me to accept a pair of values as a tuple: dateLimits, which would be of the form: (lowerDateLimit, upperDateLimit).

Is there any way for a user entering text in a console to be able to format their input so that Python would recognise it as a list or a tuple?

Or would the more Pythonic thing to do be to just use two separate parameters for the lower and upper date limits?

Comment: if you are using `input` sure they just need to enter comma separated values ... if you are using `raw_input` you will always get a string ...

Comment: What kind of formats do you want for your dates?  Would `(2013, 6, 7)` work, or do you need to parse less numerical formats like "February 13, 2013"?

Comment: Just a hint: a general parsing library (such as `ast.literal_eval`) may work but is probably too unwieldy to be a good practical choice. I suggest choosing an input format and building a parser, like @inspectorG4dget has done.

Comment: @DSM: I was hoping to parse multiple formats for dates, as text.  eg "13-Feb-2013", "February 13, 2013", "13 February 2013", "2013-02-13".

Comment: @DSM: Looks like the [dateutil](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-dateutil) is perfect for parsing multiple date formats, if I don't know which format will be used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
>>> ast.literal_eval(raw_input('Foo: '))
Foo: 1,2,3
(1, 2, 3)
```

Comment: What is the difference between ast.literal_eval() and eval()?  Is ast.literal_eval() just a safer version of eval()?

Comment: @SimonTewsi: Not only that, but it will *only* allow input that looks like a Python literal.

Comment: After playing around a bit I've decided to go with this as the solution.  One caveat for anyone else planning to use ast.literal_eval(raw_input()): I found if I tried, as the user, to enter straight text, rather than a comma-separated list, I had to enclose the text in quotes when using ast.literal_eval.  So I added a branch: For the user input expected to be a list use ast.literal_eval(raw_input()), otherwise just use raw_input() so the user does not need to enclose their entry in quotes.

Comment: Further to my comment about what I chose to do, I also used the dateutil library to parse the date text in the list the user entered into datetime objects.

Answer (score 2):

```
In [84]: nums = [int(i) for i in raw_input("Enter space separated integers: ").split()]
Enter space separated integers: 1 5 6 7 3 56  2 3 4 2 1

In [85]: nums
Out[85]: [1, 5, 6, 7, 3, 56, 2, 3, 4, 2, 1]
```

Answer (score 1):

I can't comment yet, but you if need a list instead of a tuple, ast.literal_eval can handle that by including the brackets:

```
In [1]: import ast

In [2]: ast.literal_eval('[1,2,3]')
Out[2]: [1, 2, 3]
```